# IBM DFSORT - Recuperando apenas o ano atual para comparação

Tags: dfsort

Digamos que possuo em um arquivo, uma coluna de "Ano". E gostaria de trazer no novo arquivo, apenas os registros em que o ANO seja maior que o "ano atual". Como recuperar o ano atual?

O comando `DATE1` retorna a data completa: `yyyymmdd`.

Eu necessito apenas: `yyyy`.

Exemplo:

```
INCLUDE COND=(1107,04,CH,GE,YYYY)        ** VIGENCIA >= ANO ATUAL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//GEANO    EXEC PGM=SORT 
//SYMNAMES DD * 
ESTA-ANO,S'&YR4' 
//SYMNOUT DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=* 
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=* 
//SYSIN    DD * 
  OPTION COPY 

  INCLUDE COND=(1,4,CH,GE,ESTA-ANO)
//SORTIN   DD * 
AAAA 
2017 
2012 
2013 
2014 
2015 
2014 
2014 
2019 
2031 
20E4
```

Resultos:

```
2017
2014
2015
2014
2014
2019
2031
```

&YR4 e um simbol de sistema. Podem usar com sibois de DFSORT, atraves `S'...'` em `//SYMNAMES DD`. Ver `//SYMNOUT DD` para traducao de simbois, e `SYSOUT` para traducao de cartas de controlo.

Desculpe. Eu não falo bem o português, mas falo muito DFSORT :-)